# How do I make custom names inside a node group?

Tags: texturing, shaders

[image]

I'm trying to texture a model in the shading editor with the help of node groups. I have created a node group which will contain settings for roughness, specular, metallic and emission to the principled BSDF. I managed to give the node group a name, but I would also like to change the default names for color, fac, value and so on as displayed in the image to avoid confusion. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have your group open, open the side panel and then select the *Group* tab and you will see a display like this:

[image: side panel showing Group properties]

To change a name, double click the name and type in the new name:

[image: side panel showing new name for Fac]